# NSUserDefaults correctly storing NSDate, and then returns null after 2nd retrivial

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

I am attempting to store and retrieve a `startTime` and `endTime` NSDate with NSUserDefaults.
Storing them seems to be a non issue:

```
self.convertedStringToDate = convertDate
NSLog(@"This should read 16:00: %@", self.convertedStringToDate);

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefaults setObject:convertDate forKey:@"startDate"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

I then retrieve it just to make sure it is storing and retrieving correctly:

```
NSDate* temporaryDate = (NSDate*)[userDefaults objectForKey:@"startDate"];
NSLog(@"Now User Defaults, should read 16:00: %@", temporaryDate);
```

Looking at my NSLog, everything is fine:

```
2012-07-19 14:38:26.002 app[1973:707] This should read 16:00: 2012-07-19 16:00:00 +0000
2012-07-19 14:38:26.022 app[1973:707] Now User Defaults, should read 16:00: 2012-07-19 16:00:00 +0000
```

The problem now is that when I retreive the date again, in another method, the date comes up null:

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSDate *tmpDate = (NSDate*)[userDefaults objectForKey:@"startTime"];
 NSLog(@"Retreiving date, should be 16:00: %@",tmpDate);
```

as shown in this log:

```
2012-07-19 14:38:26.107 app[1973:707] Retreiving date, should be 16:00: (null)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I also tried not retrieving the date in the check, but the date continues to return null (and also this doesn't make sense, NSUSerDefaults is a database which these keys and objects are stored). I also tried storing `retained` properties of the objects, and still to no avail. What am I missing?

**EDIT: It is important to read your own code for stupid errors.**

Comment: Do you register these keys in your initialize method in AppDelegate? Standard usage of the userDefaults says you should first register all keys you want to use with some value at initialization. Google around if you need. Otherwise you can end up with nil values.

Comment: This is now a "Notable Question"... *facepalm*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Code is correct but...

tmpDate = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"**startTime**"];

should be

tmpDate = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"**startDate**"];

Comment: I can't accept for 5 more minutes, but thank you, thank you xapslock so much! I think it's time for some less coffee...

Answer (score 4):

That's why you should always define string constants.

Answer (score 0):

Make a category on NSString and the code is:
    NSString+date.h
    @interface (NSString)
make class methods
    +(NSString)today;
     @end
     NSString+date.m 
     @implimentation (NSString)
      +(NSString)today
       {
      NSDateFormatter *formatter =      [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
       [formatter    setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatShortStyle];
       [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatShortStyle];
       NSDate *today = [NSDate Date];
       NSString *theDate = [formatter stringFromDate:today];
       Return theDate;
       }

to use just call
anywhere else in some other class
         NSString *theDate =[NSString today];
 it's that easy not messing with defaults or anything 
will give you much more time to worry about more important things 
than getting and setting the date

Comment: Although its best practice to add a special prefix to your category class methods I use DL_ or DD_Today

Comment: I really don't know where my head was earlier of course you need to save the date. Sorry